# CSV file not found

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a CSV file using python for Data Science, But received an error "ail-length-km-at-end-of-year not found."

I have tried moving my file directly to D drive so there wont be any mistakes in me writing the path director. i have tried with another test file, it works.

```
title = "Length of rails"
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()

data = np.genfromtxt('d:\rail-length-km-at-end-of-year',
                     skip_header=1,
                     dtype=[('year','U10'),('rail_type','U50'), 
('length','i8')], delimiter=",",
                     missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])

x_public = data[data['rail_type']=='public sector']['year']
y_public = data[data['rail_type']=='public sector']['length']

x_private = data[data['rail_type']=='Private Sector']['year']
y_private = data[data['rail_type']=='Private Sector']['length']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)


ax1.plot(x_public, y_public, c='b',  label='Public Sector')
ax1.plot(x_private,y_private, c='r', label='Private Sector')
plt.ylabel('rail length')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');

plt.show()
```

Python doesn't recognize the file destination

Comment: What exact error and error message do you get? Can you limit your code to just an example of the problematic code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\`-character is an escape-character. That's why the error message is not showing the "r" at the beginning - it is escaped:

> "ail-length-km-at-end-of-year not found."

`\r` is a carriage return character.
To get the correct path, you either have to escape the `\` by adding another `\` in front of it

```
data = np.genfromtxt('d:\\rail-length-km-at-end-of-year',
```

or just use a forward slash instead

```
data = np.genfromtxt('d:/rail-length-km-at-end-of-year',
```